# Does stonecoil serpent count as entering battlefield when paying X=0?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Currently building a [Purphoros, God of the forge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPurphoros%2c%20God%20of%20the%20forge%5d) deck and I'm wondering if his ability is triggered when I pay x=0 for [Stonecoil Serpent](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStonecoil%20Serpent%5d) or does it go straight to the graveyard without entering the battlefield?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Stonecoil Serpent does enter the battlefield as a 0/0 (causing Purphoros's ability to trigger), then dies immediately.**

The exact events in order in case you want them:

- Stonecoil Serpent enters the battlefield. Purphoros's ability triggers but is not put on the stack yet (603.2).
- After Serpent resolves, you would normally get priority. Since a player is about to get priority, state-based actions are checked (704.3).
- Serpent dies by state-based actions (704.5f).
- State-based actions are checked again; none are relevant so now the ability is actually put on the stack (704.3).
- State-based actions are checked one more time and then you get priority and the game proceeds normally.

The relevant parts of the rules cited above:

> 603.2. Whenever a game event or game state matches a triggered ability’s trigger event, that ability automatically triggers. The ability doesn’t do anything at this point.

> 603.3. Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority.

> 704.3. Whenever a player would get priority (see rule 117, “Timing and Priority”), the game checks for any of the listed conditions for state-based actions, then performs all applicable state-based actions simultaneously as a single event. If any state-based actions are performed as a result of a check, the check is repeated; otherwise all triggered abilities that are waiting to be put on the stack are put on the stack, then the check is repeated.

> 704.5f If a creature has toughness 0 or less, it’s put into its owner’s graveyard.

Comment: One nitpick, the rule that would cause the serpent to die is 704.5f _(If a creature has toughness 0 or less, it’s put into its owner’s graveyard. Regeneration can’t replace this event.)_, 704.5g only applies _"If a creature has toughness **greater than** 0"_